# What should be the mongodb installation and configuration recommendation in Docker swarm?

Tags: mongodb, docker-swarm

there is a production in the IoT sector that prints 5 KB of data for 15000 devices every 30 minutes. My servers are approximately 5 16 core 32 GB ram vm linux. We manage all our applications and db’s through the docker swarm cluster under these 5 VMs. 3 masters 2 workers.
We want to keep this IoT data in mongodb. Can you guide me for the most optimal performance installation? Should it be in Docker swarm under the VM for Mongo, or should I separate it in a separate VM? We are considering indexing the DeviceId and ts fields. What should our Sharding Cluster structure and numbers be? How should I configure CQRS? Currently, I have a system that has 2 shardings via Mongos and 3 replicas in each sharding, but I send the requests to Mongos and it uses a lot of CPU and RAM, and I’m also having performance problems with CQRS.
How to Example best practices docker compose file ?

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  configtsvr1:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet configReplSet --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all  
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    volumes:
      - telemetry_timeseries_config_data:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  configtsvr2:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet configReplSet --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all   
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    volumes:
      - telemetry_timeseries_config_data:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  configtsvr3:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet configReplSet --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all   
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    volumes:
      - telemetry_timeseries_config_data:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  shard1trs1:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1ReplSet --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    volumes:
      - telemetry_timeseries_shard1_data:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  shard1trs2:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1ReplSet --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all 
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    volumes:
      - telemetry_timeseries_shard1_data:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  shard1trs3:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1ReplSet --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all 
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    volumes:
      - telemetry_timeseries_shard1_data:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1


  shard2trs1:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard2ReplSet --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    volumes:
      - telemetry_timeseries_shard2_data:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  shard2trs2:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard2ReplSet --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all 
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    volumes:
      - telemetry_timeseries_shard2_data:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  shard2trs3:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard2ReplSet --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all 
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    volumes:
      - telemetry_timeseries_shard2_data:/data/db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  mongostimeseries:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongos --configdb configReplSet/configtsvr1:27017,configtsvr2:27017,configtsvr3:27017 --port 27017 --bind_ip_all
    networks:
      - data_database_layer_net
    ports:
      - "24017:27017"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

networks:
  data_database_layer_net:
    external: true

volumes:
  telemetry_timeseries_config_data:
    driver: local
  telemetry_timeseries_shard1_data:
    driver: local
  telemetry_timeseries_shard2_data:
    driver: local
```